# Checking file for text that matches input

Tags: python, file, loops, input

I have a program that needs a username system, I want the user to enter their username and the program checks the file 'username' to see if it is in the list. My code below works if there is only one person in the list, otherwise it prints correct and incorrect. How would I change my code so if just one line matches the input it prints correct.

```
username = input("enter username: ")
search = open("username", "r")
for line in search:
    if username in line:
        print ("correct")
    else:
        print ("incorrect")
```

Comment: I gather that this is a low-security application, and your users don't mind having their user names stored as plain text. ;)

Comment: Yes it is only a quiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exploit the `for...else` construct that python has.

```
with open("username") as f:
    for line in f:
        if username in line:
            print("correct")
            break
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

The `else` block is run if the program exited naturally - without breaking out from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like traditional `for` loops, then I suggest you this solution:

```
with open("username") as f:
    isInList = [username in line for line in f]:
    if any(isInList):
        print ("correct")
    else:
        print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to simply return after it finds a match. Using return and encapsulating the logic into a function would allow you to do other things with result. Also, I would suggest using the `with` statement for opening files as it has better error handling and automatically takes care of closing the file and cleanup. [Here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/) is a short tutorial on the `with` statement.

```
username = input("enter username: ")
def read_file():
    with open("username", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if username in line:
                return "correct"
        else:
            return "incorrect"
result = read_file()
print(result)
# Or do whatever else you want with the result
```